# How to get Java Resource file into byte[]?

Tags: java, eclipse, windows

I have a Java program that needs to read a file from a resource within the JAR and it only takes it through byte[]. My problem is converting the resource file from a folder within the project (i.e. tools/test.txt) into byte[]. I have tried the following (gave an "undefined for type" error):

```
final byte[] temp = new File("tools/test.txt").getBytes();
```

Another method I tried resulted in not being able to find the file:

```
 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("tools/test.txt");
 byte[] myByteArray = null;
 fos.write(myByteArray);
 fos.close();
 System.out.println("Results = " + myByteArray);
```

And lastly using Inputstream and BufferedReader. This actually gave the content of the file when running the program from Eclipse, but came out as null when running it as a jar (I am assuming that it is also not reading the file).

```
        InputStream is = null;  
        BufferedReader br = null;  
        String line;  
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();  
        try {   
              is = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("tools/test.txt");  
              br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));  
              while (null != (line = br.readLine())) {  
                 list.add(line);  
                 System.out.println("Output:" + line);
              }      

              while (null == (line = br.readLine())) {  
                     System.out.println("Error loading file:" + line);
                  }      

        }  
        catch (Exception ef) {  
          ef.printStackTrace();  
          System.out.println("Output:" + ef);
        }
```

So my question is, if I have a folder named "tools" and have a file called "test.txt", what code would I use to turn it into byte[] and still work when compiled into a Jar file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    InputStream in = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/tools/test.txt");
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    for (;;) {
        int nread = in.read(buffer);
        if (nread <= 0) {
            break;
        }
        baos.write(buffer, 0, nread);
    }
    byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
    String text = new String(data, "Windows-1252");
    Byte[] asByteObjects = new Byte[data.length];
    for (int i # 0; i < data.length: ++i) {
        asByteObjects[i] = data[i];
    }
```

Without the heading slash the path would be relative to the package of the class. A ByteArrayOutputStream serves to collect for a byte[].

If the bytes represent text is some encoding, one can turn it into a String. Here with Windows Latin-1.

---

### Since java 9 use

```
InputStream.readAllBytes()
```

Thanks for @naugler

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response. I have tried your code. However, I get a bit of a weird response. I tried printing the result of "data" and it gave me "[B@723279cf" which is weird. The text file has about 40 lines of text, none of which contain those characters. I'm not really sure what is going on, perhaps I am messing things up with the slashes?

Comment: That is a toString() from a byte[] "[B". I extend my answer.

Comment: Upon further testing, I noticed something. when printing "baos" after line baos.write(buffer, 0, nread); it has the full input of the file, however when converting it into "data" seems to be the issue. I am testing it as I go along here.

Comment: The toString of ByteArrayOutputStream converts using the current platform encoding. That is not portable, as the resource is in the encoding you used for it. (Best would be UTF-8.) Hence my String constructor.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me. However, I am stuck at the last part. the String "text" outputs contents of the file correctly now, however I need it to use it in a Byte[] format for the program I am running. I am not sure what to do now.                      Edit: Is there something wrong with using "data" for the byte[] value?

Comment: `data` is `byte[]`. `Byte` is an object wrapper for the primitive type `byte`ö. Are you sure it is `Byte[]`? I'll add anther line and then go to bed.

Comment: Thank you! Hours down the drain, but thanks to @Joop it is finally solved. Thanks again for all of your time and help.

Comment: Since Java 9, there is now `InputStream.readAllBytes()`

Comment: @naugler I have added your suggestion to the answer so people will find the right solution

Answer (score 0):

have you tried Scanner.nextByte()? make a new scanner with the file you want to parse as the input and use a for loop to create your array.

Comment: Could you please give me a link or small example of how to do it. Using byte arrays is pretty new to me and I've already spent hours trying to figure this one out.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Apache Commons File:

```
org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.resourceToByteArray("/tools/test.txt");
```